# Skylake and SSD Issues? SSD Not Found

Tags: ssd

Strange issues are confusing me with SSDs recently.

Installed Sandisk X400 SSDs into Prodesk 600 G2 Desktops, all brand new.
Every other boot, PC would say 'no OS found', but powering off and on again, it would work fine.

Installing SSD into old laptop (first gen core) it seemed to work fine. Reasoned that it was issue with Prodesk 600 G2 model.

Installing X400s into Optiplex 5040 (same spec as G2), same issue occurs- I can install windows, but Pc says 'no boot device found' on boot. Doesn't boot at all this time.

Both machines are fine with their original standard HDDs, it seems.

--

Am I missing something? Both PCs that say this are 6th gen Core Processors, could something here be the issue (though we have other skylakes with SSDs installed and they're okay). I've ordered a new Crucial brand SSD to try a different SSD altogether in case it is the X400 at fault, but it worked ok in an older laptop!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be related to UEFI-mode (UEFI or BIOS mode) and to the type of partition tables (MBR vs. GPT)? Reason: The old laptop has a BIOS, which expects MBR partition tables. The new computers have UEFI (in UEFI mode), which expects GPT partition tables. If you switch the UEFI to legacy mode, then hard drives with MBR partition tables are excepted.

Comment: The BIOS on the Dell was Legacy by default - which mode is preferred for SSDs- UEFI?

Comment: I just recalled that we have a couple of Prodesk 400 G2 Minis with SSDs, these are skylake and they have no issues..

Comment: The BIOS/UEFI mode has to correspond to the partition table type of the HDD/SSD (UEFI => GPT; legacy mode => MBR). If you have a hard drive > 2 TB or want to have more than 4 primary partitions on your hard drive, you need GPT partition tables. Is makes no difference if you have an SSD or an HDD. If the UEFI is in legacy mode: that should be fine.